# File not being created using createNewFile java method

Tags: java, java-io

I have a read method that will try to create a new file if it doesn't exist but when I run the code I get a **(The system cannot find the file specified)** error. Can someone please explain why it doesn't create the file? I would also like to know how to create the file in the parent directory rather in the one it currently saves it in?

**Code:**

```
public Set<String> readWindowTitleSet() {
    try {
        File file = new File("windowData.out");

        String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String filePath = absolutePath.
            substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));


        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath +"\\..\\" + "windowData.out");
        // this is for testing in Eclipse.


        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absolutePath);
        // This is for use in Jar file.

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        anotherList = (HashSet<String>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return anotherList;

}
```

**Error**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Joe\workspace\VocabTool\..\windowData.out (The     system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.readWindowTitleSet(WindowTitleDataStore.java:60)
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.<init>(WindowTitleDataStore.java:18)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.<clinit>(InterruptionDecision.java:23)
at view.MainGui.<init>(MainGui.java:29)
at view.MainGui.main(MainGui.java:38)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at view.MainGui.<init>(MainGui.java:29)
at view.MainGui.main(MainGui.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.<init>(WindowTitleDataStore.java:19)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.<clinit>(InterruptionDecision.java:23)
... 2 more
```

**Error after path change**

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.readWindowTitleSet(WindowTitleDataStore.java:63)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.interruptNow(InterruptionDecision.java:165)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.updateWindowTitle(InterruptionDecision.java:74)
at controller.FocusWindowName.getFocusWindowTitle(FocusWindowName.java:27)
at controller.FocusWindowName.run(FocusWindowName.java:42)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
at model.WindowTitleDataStore.getWindowDataSize(WindowTitleDataStore.java:105)
at     controller.InterruptionDecision.getWindowDataStoreSize(InterruptionDecision.java:95)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.interruptNow(InterruptionDecision.java:168)
at controller.InterruptionDecision.updateWindowTitle(InterruptionDecision.java:74)
at controller.FocusWindowName.getFocusWindowTitle(FocusWindowName.java:27)
at controller.FocusWindowName.run(FocusWindowName.java:42)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try removing "\\..\\" this and try again?

Comment: And what's the point of trying to read from a file that you just created, and which is thus empty? And why don't you use the File object you just created when instantiating the FileInputStream, instead of recreating a file path?

Comment: If you're using Java SE 7, consider to use the new NIO.2 File API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that `..` from your path

It should be
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath +"\\windowData.out");`

Instead of
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath +"\\..\\" + "windowData.out");`

Because `filePath +"\\..\\" + "windowData.out"` will be equal to `C:\Users\Joe\workspace\VocabTool\..\windowData.out` which is not a valid location of your file.

While `filePath +"\\windowData.out"` will be equal to `C:\Users\Joe\workspace\VocabTool\windowData.out` which is I guess valid location for your file( Guess you have a file windowData.out there inside the specified directory)

Comment: Actually, it should be `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);`.

Comment: I was just showing the file path mistake that OP has made

Comment: can you post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @JoeDawtry: that's precisely what happens when trying to read from an empty file you have just created. See my comment on your question.

Comment: yes, write the hashset and then try reading it.